# Converting lists as tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have the following code which gives me the following error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'Card'", where card is a class that defines the suits and ranks in a deck of cards. For example card.Card(2,2) corresponds to the "2 of Diamonds." I have the hint below, whereby "I have to encode lists as tuples because lists can't be dictionary keys"; any idea how to achieve this?

```
def test_score():
    """Test _score function"""

    test_cases = {
        # Have to encode lists as tuples because lists can't be dictionary keys
        (card.Card(2, 2), card.Card(3, 5)):7, # regular cards
        (card.Card(2, 2), card.Card(3, 1)):13, # an ace
        (card.Card(1, 13), card.Card(0, 2)):12, # a king
        (card.Card(1, 1), card.Card(0, 1)):22, # two aces, busted list
        (card.Card(1, 2), card.Card(0, 3), card.Card(3, 4)):9, # three cards
        ():0 # empty list
    }
```

Comment: Did you try making `Card` hashable?

Comment: If you have a python list you can just call tuple on it to yield a tuple e.g. `tuple([1,2,3])` returns `(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams; your post was extremely helpful; I am new to this site, unfortunately. Could you please advise how I can reward your post?